# getopt_long doesnt handle my arguments right

Tags: c++, getopt-long

```
int next_option;
int keep_content =0;
int option_index = 0;
const string short_options = "c::";


 const struct option long_options[] = 
{ 

    {"config", optional_argument, NULL, 'c'},
    {"keep", no_argument, &keep_content, 1},
    { NULL,0, NULL, 0}
};

while((next_option = getopt_long(argc,argv,short_options.c_str(),long_options,&option_index))!= -1)
{
    cout << "name: " << long_options[option_index].name  << " " << "value: " << optarg << endl;
    cout << "keep_content: " << keep_content << endl;
}
```

I have the above code where iam trying to test argument and switch parsing. The following test were made:

```
a.out -chey  --> name: config value: hey  //which is correct 
a.out -c hey  --> name:  value:           //what's wrong?
a.out --confighey  --> name:  value:      //what's wrong?
a.out --config hey  --> name:  value:     //what's wrong?
a.out -chey --keep  --> name: config value: hey  keep_content: 0 // what's wrong? keep_content should be 1
```

can you please help me understand the correct usage? what am i doing wrong?

Thank you for your time

Comment: For long options you should use the format `--long-option=value`. Also, for the last you should get the printout twice with `keep_content` correct in the second line.

Comment: I also recommend that you always check the return value, it may be `'?'` if the command line is ambiguous or have extra unrecognized parameters.

Comment: hey thanks for replying. i didn't understand what's wrong with the keep  option though, could you please clarify why it's not working? maybe an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting an optional argument and according to `man 3 getopt`:

> optstring  is  a  string  containing  the  legitimate  option characters.  If such a character is followed by a colon, the option requires an argument, so getopt() places a
>          pointer to the following text in the same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element, in optarg.  **Two colons mean an option takes an optional arg; if there  is
>          text  in  the current argv-element (i.e., in the same word as the option name itself, for example, "-oarg"), then it is returned in optarg, otherwise optarg is set to zero.**
>          This is a GNU extension.  If optstring contains W followed by a semicolon, then -W foo is treated as the long option --foo.  (The -W  option  is  reserved  by  POSIX.2  for
>          implementation extensions.)

Comment: When you process the --keep switch, optarg is a null pointer and cout fails and terminates the program before printing keep_content.

Comment: Breaking the first cout line: `cout << "name: " << long_options[option_index].name  << " " << "value: ";
    if(optarg) cout << optarg;
    cout << endl;`

Comment: I would personally use a `switch` statement inside the `while`-loop as  shown int the example in `man 3 getopt`

Comment: yes of course, the above code was just a snippet to simplify but recreate my problem. In any case thanks for pointing out ;)